# Devise: ask password only for certain situations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm developing an app using Rails and Devise for user's authentication. I wonder if there is a way to ask the password only for some changes.

For instance, I want the password to be asked when:

- Deleting the account
- Changing the password

And I want the user to be free to edit other fields without any password, such as:

- Name
- Username
- Avatar

So, I'd like a way to swap between this two methods. How can I solve this?

EDIT:

In Devise's documentation I found this and it works fine, it only allows changing password and email if I enter the password:

```
def update
    @user = User.find(current_user.id)

    successfully_updated = if needs_password?(@user, params)
        @user.update_with_password(params[:user])
    else
        # remove the virtual current_password attribute update_without_password
        # doesn't know how to ignore it
        params[:user].delete(:current_password)
        @user.update_without_password(params[:user])
    end

    if successfully_updated
        set_flash_message :notice, :updated
         # Sign in the user bypassing validation in case his password changed
         sign_in @user, :bypass => true
         redirect_to after_update_path_for(@user)
    else
         render "edit"
    end

end

private

# check if we need password to update user data
# ie if password or email was changed
# extend this as needed
def needs_password?(user, params)
    user.email != params[:user][:email] ||
    !params[:user][:password].blank?
    #HERE
end
```

Now, what could i put in `#HERE` to also require the password when I'm deleting the account?

Comment: you cannot add anything `#HERE` because the `update` method does not delete user, it's only updating user attributes. You may want to add the same kind of stuff to `destroy` method in your controller

Answer (score 3):

due to question edit:

```
def destroy
  if current_user.valid_password?(params[:user][:password])
    current_user.destroy
  else 
    render "destroy" # or what ever
  end
end
```

Comment: that is not asking for the password, is it?

Comment: @Zippie, "This method ensures that the user is logged in and if not redirects them to the login page", source:  http://asciicasts.com/episodes/210-customizing-devise

Comment: Fran posted: "I wonder if there is a way to ask the password only for some changes."

Comment: @Zippie, hmm... probably you're right. I thought of those actions as for those that required authentication

Answer (score 0):

You could create a `form_tag` redirecting to a action in your controller.

```
<%= form_tag url_for(:controller => :users, :action => :destroy), :method => :get do %>
  <%= label_tag(:password, "Enter password before deleting") %>
  <%= password_field_tag :password %>
  <%= submit_tag "Delete User With Confirmation" %>
<% end %>
```

The action in your UsersController would be something like:

```
def destroy
    if current_user.authenticate(params[:password])
         #do something
    else
         #do something
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a `destroy_with_password` method in Devise (at least since version 3.5.2).  It is in `lib/devise/models/database_authenticatable.rb` and is called by

```
destroy_with_password(current_password)
```

It destroys the record if the current_password matches, and returns false otherwise.